# Is this a Topology on X?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set and $(Y, \tau)$ be a topological space and $p:X \rightarrow Y$ a surjective function.

Define $\tau_p = \{ V\subset X : p(V) \in \tau \}$

Is $\tau_p$ a topology on X? (Prove or disprove).

I know what I have to show. I am only confused about the case of the finite intersection of elements of $\tau_p$, specifically does the fact that $p(U\cap V) \neq p(U) \cap p(V)$ unless when $p$ is injective precludes  $\tau_p$ from being closed under finite intersection? Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you think that something is not necessarily true, your next step should be to try to find a counterexample.

Comment: I know. It's difficult coming up with a counter example since the sets X & Y are not explicitly defined and also the function p.

Comment: @Josh97 when looking for a counter example you can pick any explicitly defined $X,Y$ and $p$. So look at some simple cases first and see what happens.

Comment: @CyclotomicField all the examples I could come up with proves that p(U n V) is also open which makes me to suspect that $\tau_p$ is indeed a topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us find a counterexample methodically. We want to disprove the statement. As you suggested we expect the axioms of the topology to fail in the case of finite intersections. So we need two sets $X,Y$ and a surjective map $p:X\rightarrow Y$ together with a topology $\tau$ on $Y$ and subsets $U,V\subseteq X$ such that $p(U)\in\tau$, $p(V)\in\tau$ but $p(U\cap V)\notin\tau$.

Note that always $p(\emptyset)=\emptyset \in \tau$ so we need $U\cap V\neq\emptyset$. Also $U\subseteq V$ would mean $U\cap V=U$, in which case we cannot have a contradiction $p(U)\in\tau$ and $p(U\cap V)\notin\tau$.

If we try to use finite topological spaces for counterexamples, this hints towards considering the sets $X=\{-1,0,1\}$, $U=\{-1,0\}$ and $V=\{0,1\}$. It would be nice to have $p(U)=p(V)=Y \in \tau$, so let's use the surjective map $p:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}, t \mapsto \lvert t\rvert$.

Now we just have to choose a topology. $Y=\{0,1\}$ admits three topologies, the discrete one (obviously not a good choice for a counterexample, since every image will be open), the Sierpinsky one and the indiscrete one $\tau = \{\emptyset,\{0,1\}\}$. The latter is easier, so let's try it first.

We find $p(U)=\{0,1\} \in \tau$, $p(V)=\{0,1\}\in\tau$ but $p(U\cap V) = p(\{0\}) = \{0\} \notin\tau$. It works as a counterexample.